# In IE9 the text is going down below all types of input

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have an html like follows:

```
<li class="liClass">
  <img class="dragingClass" />
  &nbsp;<img class="removeClass" />
  <label for="shoe" class="ShoeClass">
  <select class="width_150">
    <option>blackShoe</option>
    <option>greenShoe</option>
    <option>redShoe</option>
  </select>

 <label for="price" class="priceLabelClass">foo1</label>
 <input type =""text" style="width:3em" class="priceInputClass" value="" />

 <label for="minSize" class="minSizelabelClass">
 <input style="width:4em" class="minSizeInputClass" value="" />
```

My Css :

```
.liClass {
clear: left;
padding: 5px 0;
}

li.pushedProduct img.dragingClass{
float: left;
cursor: move;
}

li.pushedProduct img.removeClass{
float: left; 
padding-left:4px;
 }

.liClass label {
float: left;
padding: 0.1em 1em 0 1em;
width: 5em;
text-align: right;
 }

  label.ShoeClass {
float: left;
width: 2em;
 }

 label.priceLabelClass {
float: left;
width: 3em;
 }

  label.minSizelabelClass{
float:left;
width: 3.5em;
  }

 .liClass input {
float: left;
width: 15em;
  }


  .liClass select {
display: inline;
float: left;
width: 150px;
 }
```

The above css works fine in Firefox but in IE9 the label is going below all input boxes.I am not able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: A few errors `type =""text"`, missing `</label>` tags. Could you add the end of the concerned html : `...</li>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in agreement with Stack 101: the html was a bit unfinished and seems to be most of the problem. As pointed out already, change `type =""text"` to `type="text"` and add the missing `</label>` for shoe...as well as the ending `</li>` at the end of the code. I adjusted all the html in this example and it rectified itself: http://jsfiddle.net/GVBJW/
I don't think it was your css...just malformed html.